# Why NSMutableDictionary write crashes?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

`Writing` on background thread `NSMutableDictionary` content to file, and it crashes, why? Look line: `d.write(`

```
oqWriteFile.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;
oqWriteFile.qualityOfService = .background;

@objc static func writeFile(filePath: String, d: NSMutableDictionary) {
    print("LOG " + "Write flight: \(filePath)")
    if flightsCache[filePath] == nil {
        print("LOG " + "file path not found")
    }
    flightsCache[filePath] = d
    oqWriteFile.addOperation({
        let start = Date()
        d.write(toFile: filePath, atomically: true) // <=== BASED ON CRASH REPORT HERE IT CRASHES
        print("LOG " + "Write flight: \(String(format: "%.1f", Date().timeIntervalSince(start))) sec")
    })
}
```

Comment: Some possibilities - invalid path, dictionary contains data that cannot be written to plist, no space on disk, filepath not in app folder (cannot be accessed).

Comment: Don't use `NSMutableDictionary` at all in Swift, use native Dictionary (with `var` you get mutability for free) and `PropertyListSerialization` to write the dictionary to disk and to get an error on failure. Most likely the data in the dictionary is not property list compliant.

Comment: What's the crash reason? Also, what does the dictionary hold at the moment it's attempted for serialization?